# Iterate Go map get index

Tags: dictionary, go, go-templates, revel

In order to use `revel`'s [`even`](https://revel.github.io/manual/templates.html#even) keyword in templates I would like to get the index of a map entry when iterating with `range`. Is there any way to do so? 
My map has the structure:

```
map[string][]string
```

Comment: Your map keys are strings like "foo" and "wtf". What is an even string? That's not how things work.

Comment: Must you use `even`, or could you use CSS styling (`:nth-child(odd)`, `:nth-child(even)`) and forget about `even`?

Comment: @kennytm this actually solved my problem. If you post it as Answer I will accept it, so the case is cleared

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this only with template actions, but you may register a function which provides the necessary help.

You may register a function which returns a function (closure), which alternates its return value whenever called (exactly how "odd" and "even" indices alternate):

```
func isEven() func() bool {
    e := false
    return func() bool {
        e = !e
        return e
    }
}
```

I named it `isEven()` to not collide with ravel's `even()`. Using it:

```
func main() {
    t := template.Must(template.New("").Funcs(template.FuncMap{
        "isEven": isEven,
    }).Parse(templ))

    m := map[string]string{
        "a": "A", "b": "B", "c": "C", "d": "D",
    }
    if err := t.Execute(os.Stdout, m); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

const templ = `{{$e := isEven}}
{{- range $k, $v := . -}}
    [even:{{call $e}}] key={{$k}}; value={{$v}}
{{end}}`
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/c-HsGZjI7A)):

```
[even:true] key=a; value=A
[even:false] key=b; value=B
[even:true] key=c; value=C
[even:false] key=d; value=D
```

If you want different output for odd and even iterations, you can call `$e` in an `{{if}}` action, like this:

```
const templ = `{{$e := isEven}}
{{- range $k, $v := . -}}
    [{{if call $e}}even{{else}}odd {{end}}] key={{$k}}; value={{$v}}
{{end}}`
```

Output of this (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/IsZJY4EyG9)):

```
[even] key=a; value=A
[odd ] key=b; value=B
[even] key=c; value=C
[odd ] key=d; value=D
```

#### Under the hood

This template action:

```
{{$e := isEven}}
```

Creates a new template variable named `$e`, and its value will be the result (return value) of the `isEven()` function call. `isEven()` returns a function value, a closure that has access to a local variable `e` of type `bool`. When later you do `{{call $e}}`, you're not calling the `isEven()` Go function, but the function it returned (the closure) and is stored in `$e`. That closure has a reference to the local `bool` variable `e`, it is not "freed" until the function returned by `isEvent()` is accessible.

So whenever you do `{{call $e}}`, it calls the closure, which "has" an `e` variable of type `bool`, whose value is retained between calls of this `$e`.

If you would call `isEvent` in the template again, that would return a new function (closure), wrapping a new instance of the local variable `e`, being independent of the first wrapped variable of the closure returned by the first `isEvent()` call.

Comment: Its works, but I am curious, why does `e` not gets reset to false every time I call isEven()?

Comment: @Mrlenny Added a new **Under the hood** section to explain the internals.

Answer (score 14):

A Simple way to achieve index while looping through a map:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    mm := map[string]int{"xx" : 1, "gg" : 2}
    cnt := 0
    for a, b:= range mm{
        fmt.Println("a", a, "b",b, "c" , cnt)
        cnt++
    }
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
}
```

And prints:

```
a xx b 1 c 0
a gg b 2 c 1
Hello, playground
```

Answer (score 2):

Map entries have no index in Go; there's no way you can get an index out of any element. Also, each time you iterate on a map with `range`, you get a different order - another hint that there's no index concept in maps.

Indexes are related to ordered data structures only (e.g. arrays, slices, lists, etc), not maps. Take a look at https://blog.golang.org/go-maps-in-action for more details.

Answer (score -3):

```
{{range $key, $element := .Map}}
  {{$index := index .Map $key}}
{{end}}
```

Comment: here both $index and $element are string/[]string. But I want the number of iteration

Comment: with the edit i get ` error calling index: cannot index slice/array with type string`. I worked around it by now with help of @keynnytm's comment